# How to Create SOAP WS Client (with authentication) from WSDL in Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans, wsdl

I have to create a Web Service Client to consume a web service in netbeans. I have WSDL of that web service. I need to do a preemptive authentication in the  Client. Here is my code for that Client.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
            try
    {
    FidelioDto fd=G_jar.getInfoFidelioByND("212642098640");
    System.out.println(fd.getQualite()+" Get Qualite");
    System.out.println(fd.getCodeFidelio()+"Code Fielio");
    System.out.println(fd.getDateMaj()+" Get Date");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static FidelioDto getInfoFidelioByND(java.lang.String nd) throws AppBusinessException_Exception {
    ma.iam.wsgold.ws.impl.FidelioWebServiceImplService service = new ma.iam.wsgold.ws.impl.FidelioWebServiceImplService();
    ma.iam.wsgold.ws.impl.FidelioWebServiceImpl port = service.getFidelioWebServiceImplPort();
    BindingProvider prov = ((BindingProvider)port); 
    prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "ivr_ebou_user");
    prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "ivr+2014");

    return port.getInfoFidelioByND(nd);
}
```

}

When i have deployed this client on the server. I am getting the following error.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: j
ava.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.get
Output(HttpClientTransport.java:121)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.proce
ss(HttpTransportPipe.java:142)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.proce
ssRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processReques
t(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124
)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMetho
dHandler.java:98)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMetho
dHandler.java:78)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
        at $Proxy30.getInfoFidelioByND(Unknown Source)
```

how can i resolve this problem, any help

Answer (score 0):

You can read this link:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html

In particular, it is present a "Consuming Web Service" section where you can develop a client by following three different way:
1) you can create a Java Class in Java SE application;
2) you can create a JSP file;
3) you can create a Servlet.

In addiction, it is present this link:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/interop/reference/tutorials/doc/ClientSecurity3.html

where you can see how you can configure a security information like authentication.

Finally, you can read variuos examples about Authentication in this link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html

I hope that this response is useful for you